# Why does a wordpress know to use a specific template and how do I customize this?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello and thanks for reading. I am a .NET developer and don't know PHP (Although I am working on learning on the job) and what I am working on was made my consultants that we dont have contact with anymore. When a news post is clicked it appears to display using a template single.php. Followed is the code for this page:

```
        <div id="marketBanner">
        <div id="banner"> 
            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/services-banner.jpg" alt="" />              
        </div>
    <div id="breadcrumbWrap">
        <div id="breadcrumbs">
            <?php
            if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
            {
                bcn_display();
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="left">  
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><br />

            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
                <div class="the_details">
                    Posted: <?php the_date(); ?> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/category/recent-news/">View All News</a>
                </div>
                <?php the_content(''); ?>
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        </div>
```

Why does this page get used when a post is chosen? I want only a certain category of post to use this page and another category of post to use a different template. How do I achieve this?

Comment: RTM ->  https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to study the Wordpress Template Hierarchy @ https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display

A template (PHP file) is looked for in this order (only on wordpress).

```
 1 - single-{post_type}.php - If the post type were product, WordPress would look for single-   

 2 - product.php

 3 - single.php

 4 - index.php
```

In your case I would use single.php to create a template for *the average post* then specifically create a template for the one you want different using single-'post_type'.php

You can change the post type when creating a post.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).  It explains which templates get used and will probably be super helpful if you're just starting out with WP.  You can use WP syntax to create category pages - but at the archive level - not the single post level.

To create separate pages based on post categories see [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/alternate-single-post-template-for-specific-categories) and below:

```
<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
if (in_category(9)) {
    include (TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-specific9.php');
    return;
}
if (in_category(8)) {
    include (TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-specific8.php');
    return;
}
if (in_category(11)) {
    include (TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-specific11.php');
    return;
}
```